# Probablity for 3 balls to be common

Tags: probability, solution-verification

**The Question:**

A bag contains 10 different balls.Five balls are drawn simultaneously and then replaced and then seven balls are drawn. If the probability that exactly three balls are common to the two draws is p,then the value lf 8p is?

**My attempt:**

We need 3 balls to be common from the first draw in our final draw, therefore I will select three balls from the five which were initially drawn and 4 remaining balls from the five which were not drawn in the first draw. The number of favourable ways is $5\choose{3}$×$5\choose4$(say that this value equals x) and the total number of ways to pick 7 balls out of 10 is $10\choose7$(say that it's value is y),therefore the answer should be x/y=5/12 but the answer is given as 7/8(and hence the value of 8p=7).

What have I done wrong?

Comment: You have done nothing wrong from what I can see.  Are you sure you copied the problem correctly and looked at a solution actually related to this problem?

Comment: Yes i've checked it thrice.The answer is supposed to be an integer from 0 to 9 so obviously what i have done is wrong

Comment: I can intentionally get a wrong answer of $\frac{7}{8}$ by saying that we first pick the 7, note them and put them back, and *then* pick the five... and accidentally divide by the wrong denominator.  $\dfrac{\binom{7}{3}\binom{3}{2}}{\color{red}{\binom{10}{7}}}=\dfrac{7}{8}$.  This is wrong though because if we had rearranged things like that we are picking five balls, not seven... so it would have been $\dfrac{\binom{7}{3}\binom{3}{2}}{\binom{10}{5}}=\dfrac{5}{12}$, same as before.

Comment: The answer is indeed $\frac{5}{12}$.  There must be a mistake on the question-writers part.  This is a quintessential [hypergeometric distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution) problem, and you did it correctly.

Comment: Ok then the answer given is definitely wrong! Thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 1):

A way to do it is:

Choose the common balls first:

1. To choose 5 balls of which 3 are common, 2 are chosen in set 1 and 4 should be chosen for set 2 that should be distinct from set 1 : ${10\choose3}{7\choose2}{5\choose4}$
2. To choose 5 and 7 balls such that no extra conditions are imposed : ${10\choose5}{10\choose7}$

Get probability by using 1 and 2 as $\frac{5}{12}$.

This indeed verifies your solution.